# Find index of a given number in a list python3

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

I've written a program that gives me the index of a given integer of my choosing (x) in a list. Also, when a given integer isn't in the list, I want the program to give me the output -1 (or None).

```
list = [7,13,6,1]
x = 5
for i,j in enumerate(list):
    if j==x:
            print(i)
    else:
            print(-1)
```

However. If I use this on for instance the list given above, the output will be

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Where I only want -1. Any thoughts?
**Update**
I also want the program to give me only the index of the first integer it finds, whereas it now gives me the index of all the numbers, equal to x, which it finds in the list

Comment: Any reason you are not using `list.index`?

Comment: @timgeb Because I thought it wouldn't be able to give me the output of my choosing if the number isn't in the list?

Comment: So use `list.find`

Comment: @zondo list does not have a `.find` method...

Comment: @Whizkid95 just catch the exception and return -1, see Donkey Kong's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `else` clause will happen on each run through the loop, if you unindent it to be on the for loop instead it will only run if the `for` loop does not `break`, and if you do find one that matches then you should `break` out so that it only shows the first occurence:

```
for i,j in enumerate(list):
    if j==x:
        print(i)
        break
else:
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists),  which returns the first index value if it exists and if not raises a ValueError, and a `try`-`except` clause to handle the error:

```
l = [7,13,6,1]
x = 5

try:
    print(l.index(x))
except ValueError:
    print(-1)
```